# Parameters not sent with xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, parameters, is-empty

I am trying to sent content with an xmlHttpRequest from the client-side, but I am not able to receive those parameters on server-side.

Setting parameters on the server-side an retrieving them client-side works fine, but when I try to get on the server-side, the parameters which I am trying to set on the client side I always get an empty value / undefined.

```
node.js server side response on req.params =
...
 ( params: [] } )
...
```

any ideas why it isn't retrieving the parameters on the server-side? On server side I am using a app.post('/delete', function(req, res){ ..) where I try to console.log the req.params which should be set with the following client-side code (but doesn't) :

https://jsfiddle.net/user979979/ea2w1sn8/

Thank you!

Comment: check body-parser package, since you are sending ajax use bodyParser.json()

Comment: I think you don't use body-parser or some thing like body-parser to parse data. It will be easier for us to help you if you provide some server side code.

Comment: Thank you for the fast responses, initially I was thinking I wouldn't need body-parser because in this case I was just trying to sent a string. I installed the body-parser module, this worked fine but still no difference in the output; the server side-doesn't receive the parameters. Here is my server-side code: https://jsfiddle.net/user979979/xoom6fg3/ . Thank you!

Comment: Ok it lead me to the solution; I found that I overlooked the application/x-www-form-urlencoded format I was using, which is a format for encoding key-value pairs. So in my content/parameters I needed to separate each key-value by an & character, and each key is separated from its value by an = character and now it works fine. Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use BodyParser middleware on server side.
In your app.js, import bodyparser

`import bodyParser from 'body-parser';`

then write 

`app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));`

Now you will get your post parameters in req.body and get parameters in req.query